# googleapiclient authentication using personal account?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am having a difficult time trying to understand Google's documentation on their `googleapiclient` module authentication.

Basically, I want to connect to Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API using [a token related to] my account instead of a service account. But there does not seem to be a straight and simple documentation for that.

Can someone instruct me, with example Python code if possible, how to do that?

Just to illustrate, this is [a snippet of] the code that I have:

```
gcp_credentials = service_account.ServiceAccountCredentials \
    .from_json_keyfile_name('credentials/gce_token.json', scopes=[const.GCP_SCOPE])
gcp_http = gcp_credentials.authorize(http=build_http())
crm_service = discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', http=gcp_http)
crm_projects_api = crm_service.projects()
projects_list = crm_projects_api.list().execute()['projects']
project_id_list = [p['projectId'] for p in projects_list]
```

Feel free to ask clarification questions.

Answer (score -2):

When accessing a Google Cloud Platform API, Google recommends that you set up an API key for testing purposes only, and recommends setting up a service account for production usage. With the service account option a key can then be generated for the service account which can allow application that uses that key to assume the identity of the service account (and therefore it's associated scopes/permissions).

To create an API key (for testing only):

1) obtain OAuth 2.0 client credentials from the Google API Console.

APIs & Services > Credentials > API key

To create a service account key (for production):

1) Navigate to 'APIs & Services' > 'Credentials'

2) Click on 'Create credentials' > 'Service account key'

3) You have the option of selecting a service account that already exists, or creating a new service account (for the purpose of these steps I'll select 'create new service account')

4) Select a role that allows the access to the storage you require, for example 'Storage Admin' which allows read and write operations to the bucket(s).

5) Choose either JSON or P12 (JSON is recommended) and then hit 'Create'. The key file for the service account will be downloaded to your local machine.

The easiest way for applications to authenticate using a service account key is by utilising the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable.

You need to set this environment variable by pointing to your service account key file (the .json file downloaded when you created a service account). For example:

```
$ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path_to_service_account_file>
```

If you don't wish to use the ADC (Application Default Credentials) variable, and would like to point to the service account file in Python code instead, you can use this something like this, presuming you would like to use the storage API:

```
 def myfunction():
from google.cloud import storage

# Use service account credentials by specifying the private key
# file.
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
    'service_account.json')

# Make an authenticated API request
buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())
print(buckets)
```